# what to retrieve image from database using json ajax function in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is my first time of trying to retrieve image using ajax/json format, all other variable are displaying except the image because i dont know how integrate the  syntax in ajax,
And when i open the inspect element on the browser the name of the image is showing and it saving into the image folder as well correctly
what i just need from u guys is help me display the image inside the form without  function
Thanks in advance

This is my ajax function

```js
//Ajax Load data from ajax
    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url('person/ajax_edit/')?>/" + firstname,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {

            $('[name="id"]').val(data.id);
            $('[name="firstName"]').val(data.firstname);
            $('[name="lastName"]').val(data.lastname);
            $('[name="gender"]').val(data.gender);
            $('[name="address"]').val(data.address);
    $('[name="gender"]').val(data.gender);
    $('[name="telephone"]').val(data.telephone);
    $('[name="level"]').val(data.level);
    $('name="image"').val(data.image)
    $('[name="religion"]').val(data.religion);
    $('[name="entrance"]').val(data.entrance);
    $('[name="graduate"]').val(data.graduate);
    $('[name="parents"]').val(data.parents);
            $('[name="dob"]').datepicker('update',data.dob);
            $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
            $('.modal-title').text('Edit Person'); // Set title to Bootstrap modal title

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error get data from ajax');
        }
    });
```

This is controller

```html
public function ajax_edit($firstname)
 {
  $data = $this->person->get_by_id($firstname);
  $data->dob = ($data->dob == '0000-00-00') ? '' : $data->dob; // if 0000-00-00 set tu empty for datepicker compatibility
  
  echo json_encode($data);
 }
```

This is my model

```html
public function get_by_id($firstname)
 {
  /*
  $this->db->from($this->table);
  $this->db->where('id',$id);
  $query = $this->db->get();

  return $query->row();
  */
  
  
  $this->db->select("e.*,edu.*");
  $this->db->from("student_details e");
  $this->db->join("images edu", "edu.firstname = e.firstname", 'left');
  $this->db->where('e.firstname', $firstname);
  $result = $this->db->get();
  return $result->row();
  
 }
```

This is my view

```html
 <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Religion</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <select name="religion" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="">--Select Religion--</option>
                                    <option value="Christain">Christain</option>
                                    <option value="Muslim">Muslim</option>
                                     </select>
                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Image</label>
                        <div class="">
                            <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
                                <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"><img src="assets/img/demoUpload.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                                <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;"></div>
                                <div align="center">
                                    <span class="btn btn-file btn-primary"><span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span><span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><input type="file" name="userfile" ></span>
                                    
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
                                     <span class="help-block"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: What is image field's datatype in your database?

Comment: Your image selector in `$('name="image"').val(data.image)` is not correct.

Comment: The data field inside the database is image and the file name is userfile not image... I made a mistake inside the Ajax function nd I have corrected it bt still it's not working..

Answer (score 0):

public function DISPLAY() {

```
                $abc = "";  
               $data = $this->Model1->display('users');         
               $abc .= "<table class='table table-condensed'><th>ID</th><th>Image</th><th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th><th>Mobile</th><th>Action</th>";  
                for ($q=0; $q<count($data); $q++){ 

                $abc .= "<tr><td>".$data[$q]['ID']."</td><td>
                         **<img src='".base_url('uploads/USERS/'.$data[$q]['IMAGE'].'')."'".$data[$q]['IMAGE']." height='50' width='60'></td>**
                                <td>".$data[$q]['FNAME']."&nbsp;".$data[$q]['LNAME']."</td>     
                                <td>".$data[$q]['EMAIL']."</td>
                                <td>".$data[$q]['MOBILE']."</td>
                                <td><button id='EDIT' class= 'btn btn-primary fa fa-EDIT EDIT' value='".$data[$q]['ID']."' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'></button></td>
                                <td><button class='btn btn-danger fa fa-trash DELETE ' value='".$data[$q]['ID']."'data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'></button></td>
                                </tr></table>";}

                print_r($abc);

            }}



                 $.ajax({

                        url:'<?php echo base_url('index.php/Adminc/DISPLAY/')?>',
                        success:function(display){
                        $(".table-condensed").html(display);

                        },
                    });
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.